# What does the sum at the bottom of certain Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) queries mean?

Tags: support, data-explorer

In [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/246820/users-with-25-bountys) (and probably other) queries, there is a sum at the bottom. What does the "496" sum at the bottom mean?

[image: Screenshot of SEDE query]

I'm a bit puzzled as it's not the tally of bounties or users who have scored them. What is the explanation?

Comment: That's the tally for when P.OwnerUserID is NULL.

Comment: @Mat do you know how OwnerUserID is set to `NULL`? users that delete themselves (or get banned) have their OwnerUserID removed and that is how they get orphaned, yet the data in the User Table still shows their name? Is this how it works? Actually that is another question. Thank you for your comment, please feel free to convert it to an answer.

Comment: There's an "OwnerDisplayName" column in the posts table, that's probably where the "fantom" username is pulled for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by [mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) it will just be posts without a null `owneruserid`. It's part of a subselect in the query so the main count will still be returned while leaving the name and location blank.

That occurs when an account has been deleted or the user has requested to be disassociated with the post as part of the anonymization process, although the latter is probably a bit more unlikely with answers that have been awarded a bounty.

Comment: Thank you I understand now and probably should have guessed.